# Chrome and Nginx: strange things happen. Sometimes empty HTML page instead of PHP or static files

Tags: google-chrome, nginx

On server: nginx with php-fpm and static folder.
On client: Chrome with tab opened for a long time.
Sometimes empty HTML page is retrived instead of PHP or static file. Ajax and non-ajax queries are affected. I can see wrong answers in Network panel: 
[image]

It's not completely blank page, it's well-formatted page with doctype and head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/strict.dtd">
<!-- <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> -->
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0.1">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY><P></BODY>
</HTML>
```

One time it happened with js-file query, Chrome showed javascript syntax error.

What can it be?